# Where do I find and change user interface displays?

Tags: civicontribute

I want to edit the data-entry of events. the mask now shows the "thank you sent" field on a new event, but not on changing an existing event (it should be the other way round).
how are these displays called, i.e. where do I find them - and how can I edit them? in the menu "administration -> customize data and screens" the event-creens don't show up (some other screens are also missing)

thanks for a hint

Comment: It's difficult to tell what screens you're referring to; I don't see the field you're referring to.  Could you please a) update this question with which version of CiviCRM you're using, and b) perhaps post screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Any fields that are showing on a front-facing contribution or event page would be managed through the configuration of each contribution or event page (or the price sets or profiles associated with them) - to find the configuration area of a given contribution or event page:

1. Contributions > Manage Contribution Pages > Scroll to find the contribution page of interest, then click on the "Configure" hyperlink and select the area you wish to configure
2. Events > Manage Events > Scroll to find the event page of interest, then click on the "Configure" hyperlink and select the area you wish to configure

If you are referring to a back office registration (e.g. Event > Register Event Participant), then custom code would be required to change the data entry form.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Answer (score 0):

The UI masks you are referring to cannot easily be changed using CiviCRM settings. You would need to adapt the code / create an UI modification extension to do so. For someone familiar with CiviCRM's code this should be fairly easy.